# set manually id for row of table by JTable in joomla

Tags: joomla, components, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

i have table with field `user_id` (unique). i want set manually set it.but when i set it,JTable not insert data.
my $data array is:

```
$data['user_id']=500;
$data['name']='test';
$data['lastname']='test';
```

and my code in model is:

```
$table = $this->getTable();
        if ($table->save($data) === true) {
return $table->user_id;}
```

and my table file is:

```
   class UserproTableuser extends JTable
    {

    public function __construct(&$db)
    {
        parent::__construct('#__userpro_users', 'user_id', $db);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$table->bind($data);
$table->save();
```